# Filter array of objects based on nested properties with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have this data structure:

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'John', age: 36, color: {red: 243, green: 22, blue: 52} },
    { name: 'Jane', age: 28, color: {red: 23, green: 62, blue: 15} },
    { name: 'Lisa', age: 42, color: {red: 89, green: 10, blue: 57} }
]
```

And I want to filter it based on a list of conditions, like this (`filter` property is mapped to a predicate function from ramda):

```js
const definitions = [
    {
        id: 'name',
        filter: 'includes',
        path: [],
    },
    {
        id: 'age',
        filter: 'gte',
        path: [],
        value: 36
    }
]
```

Using this code works fine for properties that is directly on the object:

```js
const Operations = {
    includes,
    equals,
    gte
}

const filters = reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c.id] = c.value ? Operations[c.filter](c.value) : always(true);
    return a;
}, {}, definitions)

filter(where(filters), data);
```

[See Ramda playground link](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.29.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%09%7B%20name%3A%20%27John%27%2C%20age%3A%2036%2C%20color%3A%20%7Bred%3A%20243%2C%20green%3A%2022%2C%20blue%3A%2052%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%09%7B%20name%3A%20%27Jane%27%2C%20age%3A%2028%2C%20color%3A%20%7Bred%3A%2023%2C%20green%3A%2062%2C%20blue%3A%2015%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%09%7B%20name%3A%20%27Lisa%27%2C%20age%3A%2042%2C%20color%3A%20%7Bred%3A%2089%2C%20green%3A%2010%2C%20blue%3A%2057%7D%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20definitions%20%3D%20%5B%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09id%3A%20%27name%27%2C%0A%09%09filter%3A%20%27includes%27%2C%0A%09%09path%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%09%7D%2C%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09id%3A%20%27age%27%2C%0A%09%09filter%3A%20%27gte%27%2C%0A%09%09path%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%0A%09%09value%3A%2036%0A%09%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20Operations%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09includes%2C%0A%09equals%2C%0A%20%20%20%20gte%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20filters%20%3D%20reduce%28%28a%2C%20c%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09a%5Bc.id%5D%20%3D%20c.value%20%3F%20Operations%5Bc.filter%5D%28c.value%29%20%3A%20always%28true%29%3B%0A%09return%20a%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20definitions%29%0A%0Afilter%28where%28filters%29%2C%20data%29%3B)

Problem is, I want to introduce other filter conditions that operate on nested structures. For that I introduced a path property, that would take an array of strings that represents the path where the property is located on the object:

```js
const definitions = [
    {
        id: 'name',
        filter: 'includes',
        path: [],
    },
    {
        id: 'age',
        filter: 'gte',
        path: [],
        value: 36
    },
    {
        id: 'red',
        filter: 'gte',
        path: ['color', 'red'],
        value: 40
    },
    {
        id: 'blue',
        filter: 'gte',
        path: ['color', 'blue']
    }
]
```

This should result in (filters only take effect when there is a `value` exist in the definition):

```
{
    age: 36,
    color: {
        blue: 52,
        green: 22,
        red: 243
    },
    name: "John"
}
```

However, I can't make it work with `where`.
I could pre-map the array to bring the nested
properties to the uppermost level of the objects, but I guess there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I found out eventually, just have to drop `where` and change it to use `allPass`:

```js
const filtered = filter(allPass(values(activeFilters)), data);
```

And change the reducer to:

```js
reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c.id] = (val) => {
        const getPath = c.path ? path([...c.path, c.id]) : path([c.id])
        return c?.value ? FilterOperations[c.active](c.value)(getPath(val)) : always(true);
    }
    return a;
}, {}, definitions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest `pathSatisfies` but you'd have to switch `gte` for `lte`.

```js
const createPredicates = R.reduce((res, def) => {
  const predicate = def.value 
    ? R.pathSatisfies(R[def.filter](def.value), def.path)
    : R.T;

  return [...res, predicate];
}, []);

const data = [
  { name: 'John', age: 36, color: {red: 243, green: 22, blue: 52} },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 28, color: {red: 23, green: 62, blue: 15} },
  { name: 'Lisa', age: 42, color: {red: 89, green: 10, blue: 57} }
];

const definitions = [
  {
    id: 'name',
    filter: 'includes',
    path: [],
  },
  {
    id: 'age',
    filter: 'lte',
    path: ['age'],
    value: 36
  },
  {
    id: 'red',
    filter: 'lte',
    path: ['color', 'red'],
    value: 40
  },
  {
    id: 'blue',
    filter: 'lte',
    path: ['color', 'blue']
  }
];

const fn = R.filter(
  R.allPass(createPredicates(definitions)),
);

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-J4Em3sC41YRNdTfPiA2QTHFVyPP7Qqpac9s+sb4p4bdfZfiJai2s1EXZcDB+V0r23kYc42p/cFVlrbz7/1Zwjg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```